# read_hdf where fails 'all of the variables refrences must be a reference to an axis...'

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

Stuck on the following.

```
log_iter = pd.read_hdf(FN, dspath, 
                       where = [pd.Term('hashID','=',idList)],
                       iterator=True, 
                       chunksize=3000)
```

The dspath has 35 columns and can be quite large causing MemoryError.

So trying to go the iteator/chunksize route.   But the 'where=' clause is failing with

```
ValueError: The passed where expression: [hashID=[147685,...,147197]]
        contains an invalid variable reference
        all of the variable refrences must be a reference to
        an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
        The currently defined references are: ** list of column names **
```

The problem is that hashID is not in the list of column names.  Yet, if I do

```
read_hdf(FN, dspath).columns
```

The hashID is in the columns. Any suggestions?  My goal is to read in all rows x 35 columns whose hashID is in idList.

Update.  The following works and shows that the hashID exists as a column once the dataset is read in.

```
def dsIterator(self, q, idList):
    hID = u'hashID'
    FN = self.db._hdf_FN()
    dspath = self.getdatasetname(q)
    log_iter = pd.read_hdf(FN, dspath, 
                           #where = [pd.Term(u'logid_hashID','=',idList)],
                           iterator=True, 
                           chunksize=30000)
    n_all = 0
    retDF = None
    for dfChunk in log_iter:
        goodChunk = dfChunk.loc[dfChunk[hID].isin(idList)]
        if retDF is None : retDF = goodChunk
        else: 
            retDF = pd.concat([retDF, goodChunk], ignore_index=True)
        n_all += dfChunk[hID].count()
    n_ret = retDF[hID].count()
    return retDF
```

Comment: Note, I am using python2.  Thus the 'hashID' has to use u'hashID' as the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
log_iter = pd.read_hdf(FN, dspath, 
              where = ['logid_hashID={:d}'.format(id_) for id_ in idList]
              iterator=True, 
              chunksize=3000)
```

work?

If the `idList` is large, this might be a bad idea.